# cassandra extract month from timestamp

Tags: cassandra, database, nosql

In Postgres, we have function to extract MONTH, YEAR etc from timestamp using EXTRACT function. See below.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
```

Is it possible to do the same in cassandra? Is there a function for this?

If it is possible, I can then run queries such as find all entries in year "2015" and month "may". This is possible in postgres using EXTRACT function.

Comment: There is no such thing available in Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have the answer, but you can create a function in your keyspace like this:

```
cqlsh> use keyspace; 

cqlsh:keyspace> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION YEAR (input TIMESTAMP)
     RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS TEXT
     LANGUAGE java AS 'return input.toString().substring(0,4);';

cqlsh:kespace> SELECT YEAR('2001-02-16 20:38:40') as year FROM ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra you would handle that a little differently.  You can have fields in your table of type timestamp or timeuuid, and then use that field in a time range query.

For example if you wanted all entries for 2015 and May and have a timestamp field called 'date', you could do a query like this:

```
SELECT * from mytable where date > '2015-05-01' and date < '2015-06-01' allow filtering;
```

You can use a number of different formats for specifying the date to specify the time more precisely (such as down to fractions of seconds).

Cassandra converts date strings using the org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils class, and allows the following date formats:

```
private static final String[] dateStringPatterns = new String[] {
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmXXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmXXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",
        "yyyy-MM-dd",
        "yyyy-MM-ddX",
        "yyyy-MM-ddXX",
        "yyyy-MM-ddXXX"
};
```

But note that Cassandra is not as good at ad hoc queries as a relational database like Postgres. So typically you would set up your table schema to group the time ranges you wanted to query into separate partitions within a table.